# Java heap overflow during serialisation of object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of arraylist of float containing some values and 3 more arraylist of integers

For the arraylist of arraylist of floats, the number of rows is 47 and the number of columns is 44300. So when I tried to serialize the object containing all these arraylists into the object, I have a heap overflow error.

I used arraylist of arraylist is because the number of columns is not predetermined before a function call, hence has to be dynamic. I believe this arraylist of arraylist is causing the problem.

Is there any way to implement a dynamic 2d array better and with less memory?

Many thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4):

```
8(float size) * 47* 44300 = 16656800 bytes-->16 MB
```

Now if you consider 3 more ArrayList of integers

```
4(int size) * 47* 44300 = 8328400 bytes-->8 MB * 3-->24 MB
```

My opinion is check how much is the heap space and increase it. Changing collection to array will be really micro benchmarking.

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size

java -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```